How to log into cloud storage via CLI without API
I've bought some cloud space from the local provider. Can log via browser or Android app, but there is no API.
I want to log via CLI and upload/download files using same method. Hosting provider is not responsive to messages and gives vague answers regarding API.
Only info I have is the IP address.
Is it somehow possible to find out which port is used for logging and data transfer?
Thanks!
